# what is the most efficient way to maintain a tagged and latest docker image version

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am working on a `jenkins` build script to build a new docker image and then push it to `Dockerhub`.

In order to push `me/my-image:123` and `me/my-image:latest`, I currently have something like this:

```
TAG_IMAGE=me/my-image:123
LATEST=me/my-image:latest

docker build --rm -t $TAG_IMAGE .
docker tag -f $TAG_IMAGE $LATEST
docker push $TAG_IMAGE
docker push $LATEST
```

Is there any way to accomplish this in less than 4 commands?

Comment: thx @Rolice, i was just trying to fix that formatting

Comment: Ye, no problem. I saw you have used markdown, but here the formatting is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
docker build --rm $TAG_IMAGE:latest .
docker push $TAG_IMAGE:latest
```

Comment: true, but i also want a specific tag version available as well as just `latest` (this allows for forced pull when tag changes)...

Comment: @tony_k don't think there's any shorter way to do that